# Hide echo output, when text file is empty

Tags: php

I have a blog/vlog where I also share my listening habits from Spotify live.
I use a little snippet called Snip (available on Github) that fetches my Spotify stream, creates text files for my data (like track, artist, album and trackID)

Now I wanted to add a link on my webpage to the actual track I am playing using the variable $i for trackID

I've come up with this code thanks to some googling and tips/trix pages:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("Snip_TrackId.txt", "r") or die("Die!"); 
echo "<a href='https://open.spotify.com/track/";
echo fread($myfile,filesize("Snip_TrackId.txt"));
echo "'target='_blank'><img width='18px' height='18px' title='Open with Spotify' src='np_spotify.png'><a/> <- Listen";
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

This works just fine, but when I close down Spotify or pause, the text files empty themselves and my info box turns blank AND THAT'S THE WAY IT SHOULD BE :).
B
ut...... With my code above, the link, image and text "<- Listen" is still visible and I've been trying to figure out how I can fix this but I'm stuck.
(The link is also not really working as it only points to the part without the trackID)

So now I turn to you. Can you help me with a working solution for this?
If not, I will probably just keep things as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before writing a link check file for emptiness for example:

```
$file = "Snip_TrackId.txt";
if (0 < filesize($file)) {
    $myfile = fopen("Snip_TrackId.txt", "r") or die("Die!"); 
    echo "<a href='https://open.spotify.com/track/";
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("Snip_TrackId.txt"));
    echo "'target='_blank'><img width='18px' height='18px' title='Open with   Spotify' src='np_spotify.png'><a/> <- Listen";
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Or if file contains spaces - check read data:

```
$myfile = fopen("Snip_TrackId.txt", "r") or die("Die!"); 
$data = trim(fread($myfile,filesize("Snip_TrackId.txt")));
if ($data) {
    echo "<a href='https://open.spotify.com/track/";
    echo $data;
    echo "'target='_blank'><img width='18px' height='18px' title='Open with   Spotify' src='np_spotify.png'><a/> <- Listen";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just check the filesize before reading it:

```
<?php 
if ((int)filesize("Snip_TrackId.txt") > 0)
{
    $myfile = fopen("Snip_TrackId.txt", "r") or die("Die!");
    echo "<a href='https://open.spotify.com/track/";
    echo fread($myfile, filesize("Snip_TrackId.txt"));
    echo "'target='_blank'><img width='18px' height='18px' title='Open with Spotify' src='np_spotify.png'><a/> <- Listen";
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving this for me. I found all three answers working fine. Tried to up-vote all of them, but since Iäm new here that didn't work :)
I ended up using the first one, that checks if the file is empty or not.

Comment: I also ended up adding an 'else statement' like

`else {
    echo "Nothing to see here";
}`
but I'm not sure I'll use that one. The empty box looks fine to me. Thanks again for the help